# Why doesn't `autocmd InsertLeave * :setlocal relativenumber` get executed when I leave Insert mode using Ctrl-C?

Tags: autocmd

I've defined the following `autocmd`s, which active/deactivate relative line numbers, depending on whether I'm in Insert mode or not:

```
" Relative line numbers, except Insert mode
augroup toggle_relative_number
autocmd InsertEnter * :setlocal norelativenumber
autocmd InsertLeave * :setlocal relativenumber
```

The problem I'm facing is that `autocmd InsertLeave * :setlocal relativenumber` only gets executed, when I leave Insert mode using Escape - **not** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

How can I also execute the `autocmd`, when I leave Insert mode using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.?

Answer (score 2):

From `:h i_CTRL-C` (emphasis mine):

> Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for abbreviations.  **Does not trigger the [InsertLeave](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#InsertLeave) autocommand event**.

However, you could remap `<C-c>` as follows:

```
inoremap <C-c> <C-c>:doautocmd InsertLeave<CR>
```

if you **really** want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

See:

```
:h i_CTRL-C
:h :doautocmd
:h InsertLeave
```

Comment: Iow, don’t use C-c :) it breaks a lot things

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: do never map `<c-c>`, you loose the ability to break existing running scripts.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Would it be OK to map `<C-c>` as in the second example? It still sends `<C-c>` at the end, with additional steps.

Comment: @JakeGrossman I am not sure. I thought as soon as you map `<c-c>` to something, you loose the ability to interrupt anything. even when it contains another `<c-c>`. But from my limited testing it seems to work. But I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - Why shouldn't it work? It the mapping contains `C-c` and it's non-recursive, then it should function as pressing `C-c`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - Is it possible to trigger `InsertLeave` event, when pressing `C-c` in normal mode? I.e. `inoremap <c-c> "fire InsertLeave"<c-c>`, or would that break things? When would I ever need to terminate running scripts, while in Insert mode?

Comment: I've edited my post to match your edited question.

Comment: @Shuzheng well, because that is the way it *works*