# What is the reason to not have <C-c> trigger InsertLeave event?

Tags: neovim, events

In the past, I had a problem with the diagnostics virtual text not coming back after exiting insert mode.
After a few hours of searching I just gave up.

Today I have spend 2 hours trying to get my `autocmd` to dismiss copilot ghost text when exiting insert mode. (Very annoying to have this text still there)
I needed it to execute on `InsertLeavePre` event.

Found out now that <kbd>Ctrl c</kbd> does not trigger the `InsertLeave` and `InsertLeavePre` events.
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/21563

I have learnt my lesson and will now map `<C-c>` to `<Esc>` :)

But all of this comes down to my question. Why? What I'm I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're going to like this answer because it's a bit circular, but it's so you can [leave Insert mode without triggering `InsertLeave` or abbreviations](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-C)!

Traditionally `Ctrl-C` is used for aborting things, so think of it as "aborting" insert mode: it's used when you want Vim to stop insert mode *immediately*, without doing anything else.

As a side-note, [the current lead developer of Vim recommends against mapping `<C-C>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27194/why-doesnt-autocmd-insertleave-setlocal-relativenumber-get-executed-when-i#comment48962_27196). It might be better just to get used to using `<Esc>` or `Ctrl-[` instead, if that's something your muscle memory will allow.

Comment: C-c also, for example, cancels repeats when prefixing insert-mode operations with counts. It really is “stop this now.” Just use Esc :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Make sense for the <C-c> and thus to differentiate the two.